# Parameter values swapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The values in my parameters are swapping with each other and I can't see any reason for it.

In my controller, I return data from my repository with

`UserTeam ut = _UserTeamRepository.GetUserTeam(userteamid:0, gameid: gameid, userid: UserID);`,

When I reach the breakpoint in the controller at the line above,

gameid=1
userid=2

This is correct.  However, when (again debugging), I reach the breakpoint inside the GetUserTeam repository method:

`public UserTeam GetUserTeam(int userteamid = 0, int gameid = 0, int userid = 0)`

they have magically switched - gameid is now 2, userid is 1.

Is this a bug?  What is going on?

Comment: Silly question but: are you sure you aren't changing the values elsewhere?

Comment: How? The GetUserTeam method is called & at that instant they are switched - before another line of code is encountered.

Comment: Asking because your code is valid. Try to pass in hardcoded values  with  and without named arguments to see if it is the same problem.

Comment: Have found the problem. Mainly; that I am an idiot. The interface for the UserTeam repository had the user team method stub defined as GetUserTeam(userteamid, userid, gameid);,

Comment: Upvoted. This question has an interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion with named parameters when the names of the parameters are not the same in the interface (or virtual method of base class) as they are in the implementing (overriding) method. Consider this

```
interface IFace
{
  void M(int user, int game);
}
class C : IFace
{
  public void M(int game, int user) // note order here
  {
  {
}
```

Then calling `M` using named parameter syntax leads to confusion, especially since intellisense gets it wrong.

The well-known authority Eric Lippert writes [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774898/1336654) on Stack Overflow:

> Overload resolution uses the *names* from the *more* derived version.
>   This is an unfortunate consequence of the fact that named arguments
>   were added very late in the game.