# Compiling generic interface vs generic abstract class & params keyword

Tags: c#, .net, interface, compiler-errors, abstract-class

**Consider the followng example - this uses an interface:**

```
public interface IAlgorithm<TResult, TInput>
{
    TResult Compute(TInput input);
}

class A : IAlgorithm<int, byte[]>
{
    // Notice the use of params...not strictly what the interface specifies but it works.
    public int Compute(params byte[] input)
    {
        // no sane developer would go to this length to prove a point
        return input[0];
    }
}

A inst = new A();
Console.WriteLine(inst.Compute(1, 2, 3));
// 1
```

This example shows an interface, where it's method implementation (`params byte[]`) deos not exactly match the interface contract (`byte[]`)...but it works!

**Consider the followng example - this uses an abstract class:**

```
public abstract class Algorithm<TResult, TInput>
{
    public abstract TResult Compute(TInput input);
}

class A : Algorithm<int, byte[]>
{
    // Notice the use of params...not strictly what the abstract class specifies, and it causes the compile to burst into tears!
    public override int Compute(params byte[] input)
    {
        // no sane developer would go to this length to prove a point
        return input[0];
    }
}

A inst = new A();
Console.WriteLine(inst.Compute(1, 2, 3));
//Compiler error: No overload for method 'Compute' takes 3 arguments
```

I want to know why this works for an interface, but not for an abstract class?

Comment: Can you change the type of `inst` in each example to match the abstract type: `IAlgorithm<int, byte[]>` and see what happens?  It looks like the first version is using the `Compute` method from the class declaration directly and not via the interface.

Comment: @MikeofSST Very interesting.  IAlgorithm<int, byte[]> inst = new A();
 Console.WriteLine(inst.Compute(1, 2, 3)); naturally throws the error you'd expect :)

Comment: Because the interface implementation satisfies the interface (i.e. it gives you a method that will receive a byte array) it is valid but the override of the abstract class is *not* valid because the signature of the overriding method doesn't match exactly. It works because the interface effectively only imposes a subset of what you can pass as an argument so you *can* use that method as a fully-working implementation of the one declared in the interface.

Comment: I believe that this question is about difference between rules for matching interface implementation vs. virtual overrides matching - so while it is partially answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774529/changing-the-params-modifier-in-a-method-override thee is still second half about interface, so I don't think whole question is duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Question is still a duplicate. It is slightly reworded. It can be interpreted as why the method first declared as a params works whilst it is ignored when overriding it. Answer is for abstract class method is not first declared in `A`, it is in `Algorithm` and thus method modifiers are taken from base class. Do note that Vs2014 with resharper gives a warning that params will be ignored when overriding, IMHO this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you are right. after re-reading question couple more times - yes, it is exact duplicate. In both cases classes themselves compile fine and really the only question here is why invocation of overriden method ignores `params`. Re-resolved as duplicate.

Comment: Side note: (not serious) strictly speaking it could have been downvoted into oblivion despite being well written interesting question as it does not provide *absolutely minimal* sample - knowing the answer there is nothing to do with generics at all.